# Jquery -Regex - Require first 10 characters of every line in Multiple text

Tags: jquery, regex

I have one multiline text box. This box contains large string which has new line breaks.I want to display first 10 chars of each line or paragraph in a multiple text. My multiple text box contains more than 100k chars. Is there any best solution to retrieve string using regex?

Example input:

```
this is sample test
I am from australia
I am from India
```

The expected output is the first 10 chars of each new line/paragraph followed by `...`

```
this is sam...
I am from a..
I am from I..
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex to find the first 10 characters: [`^(.{10})(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/lShEQC/5) and replace with `$1...`

```
output = input.replace(/^(.{10})(.*)$/gm, '$0...')
print(output[<line>])
```

Note this will match `I am from␠` instead of `I am from a` because it counts spaces too.